# Ionic app freezes on load

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, freeze

I have an ionic app that im pretty far along with that now freezes on load. After doing some research, i think that it could be due to my config.xml file.

This is the core of the file (minus the app id and other app sensitive stuff):

```
<content src="index.html" />

<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />
<allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />

<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<feature name="SocialSharing">
    <param name="id" value="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
    <param name="url" value="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
    <param name="url" value="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>

<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" />

<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" spec="~1.0.0" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.0.8" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" spec="~0.3.0" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.5.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="~0.7.2" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativeaudio" spec="~3.0.6" />
```

can anyone offer guidance on if anything would freeze up the application on load?

THanks

Comment: at what point does it freeze? Is this on device/emulator or ionic serve. If on device does it get past the splash screen and does it show html or white screen? What does it say in the console?

Comment: I don't get a console error. It happens on a device and emulator (iOS only tested so far). The splash screen comes up, then a white screen (I think is the firebase social login pop up) it then freezes on the default view just before loading the data. If I shut down the app an rerun it, it sometimes will run fine. I also thought it may be a routing auth issue. But Google pointed to the config.xml file.

Comment: @Ant anything that you can suggest?

Comment: Try removing CDVWKWebViewEngine feature and preference. It was causing issues in several projects I worked on. Yes, performance won't be that good but there is chance your app will work without it.

Comment: @avladov thanks on an emulator it is running smoother. Ill try on a device when i get home. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your cordova-ios to 4.2.0

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios@4.2.0
```